# Cursor Movement in y8k vs y8j

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-movement

Why does `y8j` not move the cursor but `y8k` does move it up?

What .vimrc entry would prevent yanking upwards moving the cursor?

Comment: Now that I have and understand the answer:
Possibly duplicate of/related to: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9997/21804

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, for commands that involve `{motion}`, the cursor is placed at the *beginning* of the resulting text area. `y8j` starts at the current position and moves down, so the cursor does not move. `y8k` only includes the current line as the last yanked one, so it moves the cursor to the *first* yanked line, i.e. up. The same happens with motions inside a single line, e.g. `y8w` (does not move) / `y8ge` (moves, as start is before cursor) / `yiw` (moves if the cursor is inside the current word vs. at the start of it).

To return the cursor to the original position, you can explicitly set a mark and return to it after the yank: ``` m'y8k`` ```. Some [jump-motions](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#jump-motions) automatically record a jump (but not `k`), so you can skip the `m'`.

Comment: Ah okay that makes way more sense thatn I thought. Thank you for the great answer!